# SDE driven by Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, poisson-process, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose that $(N_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R}^+}$ is a Poisson process with intensity  $\lambda$>0 and that $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ being a stochastic process which solves the following SDE:$$dX_t=aX_t^-dN_t$$ Now I want to find an explicit representation for $X$ in terms of $X_0,a$ and $N_t$.Now I would like to try the change of variables $Z_t=log(aX_t)$ and use Ito's Lemma, however the material I have been given is very sparse and as far as I can see only applicable to SDEs driven by Brownian motions. So my question is if anyone could give a hint on how to solve this equation or any relevant material concerning similar SDEs.

Comment: The three key things to keep in mind with Poisson processes are 1) the "definition" $\mathrm{d}N_t\sim\mathcal{Poisson}(\lambda\mathrm{d}t)$, hence 2) the powers $\mathrm{d}N_t{}^n = \mathrm{d}N_t$ $\forall n \ge1$, and 3) the "new" Ito's lemma $$\mathrm{d}(f(X_t,t)) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(X_t,t) + \mu(X_t,t)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(X_t,t)\right)\mathrm{d}t + \left(f(X_t+\nu(X_t,t),t)-f(X_t,t)\right)\mathrm{d}N_t$$ where $\mathrm{d}X_t = \mu(X_t,t)\mathrm{d}t+\nu(X_t,t)\mathrm{d}N_t$.

Comment: @KurtG. Did you consider compensated Poisson process ?

Comment: @Abezhiko Sorry I was wrong. Assuming OP wants an uncompensated PP $N_t$ we can first find the [Doleans-Dade exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dol%C3%A9ans-Dade_exponential#General_formula_and_special_cases) $Y_t={\cal E}(aN_t-a\lambda t)$ of the compensated PP times $a$ which should be $Y_t=X_0(1+a)^{N_t}e^{-a \lambda t}\,.$ Then $X_t=Y_te^{a\lambda t}=X_0(1+a)^{N_t}$ should be OP's seeked solution.

Comment: @KurtG I suspect non of this helps me, as I am not allowed to use this material, perhaps it is possible to just solve the Integral $\int_0^t aX_t^-dN(t)$? I know this is equal to the sum $\sum_{0<s\leq t}aX_s^-\Delta N(s)$ but I dont know how to simplify here either so I am really stuck.

Comment: You wrote in OP that you would like to use Ito's lemma. Then apply it to see how my solution solve the SDE. This boils down to plugging it into your sum formula.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP seems to ask for a solution that is based on inappropriate teaching material covering only Brownian motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know
$$\tag{1}
\int_0^t aX_{s-}\,dN_s=\sum\limits_{0<s\leq t}aX_{s-}\Delta N_s\,.
$$
The SDE
$$\tag{2}
dX_t=aX_{t-}\,dN_t
$$
is nothing else than the integral equation
$$\tag{3}
X_t=1+\int_0^t aX_{s-}\,dN_s\,.
$$
and the proposed solution of this SDE is
$$\tag{4}
X_t=X_0(1+a)^{N_t}\,.
$$
*Proof.* The $X_t$ in (4) changes only by jumps of $N_t$ and only by the amount
$$\tag{5}
\Delta X_t=X_t-X_{t-}=X_0(1+a)^{N_{t-}+1}-X_{t-}=(1+a)X_{t-}-X_{t-}=aX_{t-}\,.
$$
if and only if there is a jump of $N_t$ in $t\,.$ This can be written as
$$
\Delta X_t=aX_{t-}\Delta N_t
$$
which is the discrete version of the SDE (2). Due to the properties of $X_t$ (changes only by jumps) the integral equation (3) follows now from (1).
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$

Comment: yea this looks about right, Idk why my prof went full SDE after introducing the most general form of Ito Lemma and not giving any more examples or specific cases. I feel left in the dark. Thanks a lot anyways

Comment: @MathR This example is the core of Merton's jump diffusion model from mathematical finance. It shows how essential parts of SDEs driven by discontinous processes could be delivered at almost zero cost. A book by B. Lapeyre is to my knoledge the only one that follows this route.

Comment: One last question how is do you get equality in (5)? The $N_t +1$  is the moment N jumps and the left limit aka $X_t^-$ doesnt change becuase of not being left continuous right?

Comment: Yes. Both $N$ and $X$ are *right* continuous. When $N$ jumps in $t$ then $N_{t-}+1=N_t\,.$